# YouTube homepage looks zoomed, it only shows 2 videos in 1 row

Tags: youtube, google-account

This is how it looks: 
[It looks like this when i open homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsPvu.jpg)

The thing is that when I change account it works normal.

It behaves like this only on homepage and in all browsers, on all computers with different screen sizes but only when I am logged in with my account.

What to do? I could really use some help.

Thank you.

Comment: Google often tests new features on their websites for a limited number of users.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that I have another account which when I use it behaves same as first one but when I use my brother's account or my third account that is not used very often it works properly. I hope I was clear in this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is currently testing larger thumbnails for some users, which is why you can see it while logged in but not necessarily on other's accounts. An [article from the Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2019/8/13/20803795/youtube-thumbnails-home-page-redesign) does contain a comment from YouTube:

> Videos are no longer grouped by categories, fewer videos appear in a line for people to scroll through, and, yes, the thumbnails are noticeably larger. It’s unclear just how many people have been served the new layout. We weren’t able to get the design to appear ourselves, so it’s likely a limited test for now. A YouTube spokesperson told The Verge the company is “currently testing a new homepage layout to improve the watch experience for our users.”

There is nothing further officially on this change, or information on how to return to the original layout as yet.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought there was something wrong with my account. I am pretty relieved right now knowing there isn't. Is there a way to follow news about this changes?

Comment: It came back normal now. It's not zoomed anymore.